# Firing a storyboard in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have many of theses:

```
<Image x:Name="Foo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="1.png" Style="{StaticResource imageStyle}" 
                       ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="360000" ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="10000" ToolTip="fffffff"/>

<Image x:Name="Foo2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="2.png" Style="{StaticResource imageStyle}" 
                       ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="360000" ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="10000" ToolTip="eeeeeeeee"/>

<Image x:Name="Foo3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Source="3.png" Style="{StaticResource imageStyle}" 
                       ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="360000" ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="10000" ToolTip="ddddddddddddd"/>
```

And right now my animation storyboard only fires when someone clicks the `Foo` image.

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseDown" SourceName="Foo">
        <BeginStoryboard Name="mySlider">
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentHolder"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    Duration="0:0:1" From="0 0 0 0" To="-800 0 0 0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

How can I make the animation fire if someone clicks on any one of the three images above? The thing they share in common is the style, so maybe there's some way to use that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Grid` with trigger is a parent for all that images, then `MouseDown` event will bubble up to it from every Image anyway, so all you have to do is to remove `SourceName` setting from trigger.

Otherwise you can set `SourceName` to Image`s parent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it is that you don't want to repeat the same `EventTrigger` multiple times, once for each source. If you leave out the `SourceName` then your animation will start for any unhandled `MouseDown` routed event even if it is not from one of your images (since `MouseDown` is a very generic bubbling routed event).

One solution would be to have a custom `Image` class (perhaps called `MyImage`) which will detect when a `MouseDown` event happens, and in response fire a very custom `RoutedEvent` (say `MyImageRoutedEvent`). Your `EventTrigger` then could listen for `MyImageRoutedEvent` instead, since only `MyImage` can fire this event. Hence your animation only runs if the `MouseDown` event is from one of your `MyImage` instances.

Alternatively, you could achieve this behaviour through an attached behaviour. The idea would be that the behaviour is configured to intercept a specified event (via an attached property) and when that event is fired from an element participating in the behaviour, the event is marked as handled and a new custom event is fired instead. Your `EventTrigger` would then listen for the new custom event.

Example XAML:

```
<StackPanel>

    <StackPanel.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="rectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="l:EventInterceptBehaviour.OriginalRoutedEvent" Value="UIElement.MouseDown" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectangleStyle}" Fill="Red" />
                            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectangleStyle}" Fill="Green" />
                            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectangleStyle}" Fill="Blue" />
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" x:Name="contentBorder">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="l:EventInterceptBehaviour.InterceptedEvent">
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="mySlider">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentBorder"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                                                            Duration="0:0:1" To="10" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="Content Placeholder" />

</StackPanel>
```

Example behaviour:

```
public static class EventInterceptBehaviour
{
    #region InterceptedEvent Attached Routed Event

    public static readonly RoutedEvent InterceptedEventEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("InterceptedEvent",
                                                                                  RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                                                                                  typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                                                                                  typeof(EventInterceptBehaviour));

    public static void AddInterceptedEventHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        if (d is FrameworkElement)
        {
            var element = (FrameworkElement)d;
            element.AddHandler(InterceptedEventEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveInterceptedEventHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        if (d is FrameworkElement)
        {
            var element = (FrameworkElement)d;
            element.RemoveHandler(InterceptedEventEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region OriginalRoutedEvent Attached Dependency Property

    public static void SetOriginalRoutedEvent(FrameworkElement element, RoutedEvent value)
    {
        element.SetValue(OriginalRoutedEventProperty, value);
    }

    public static RoutedEvent GetOriginalRoutedEvent(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return (RoutedEvent)element.GetValue(OriginalRoutedEventProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalRoutedEventProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("OriginalRoutedEvent", typeof(RoutedEvent),
                                            typeof(EventInterceptBehaviour),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnOriginalRoutedEventPropertyChanged));

    #endregion

    private static void OnOriginalRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(InterceptedEventEvent, element));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private static void OnOriginalRoutedEventPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is FrameworkElement)
        {
            var element = (FrameworkElement)d;
            element.AddHandler((RoutedEvent)e.NewValue, new RoutedEventHandler(OnOriginalRoutedEvent));
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, a style is applied to each `Rectangle` and the attached behaviour is configured to intercept the `MouseDown` routed event, and replace this event with the `InterceptedEvent`. The animation then only runs if an `InterceptedEvent` is fired.

Hope this helps!